# Dynamic Table Height according to number of cell in table

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am developing app that puts the data in UILable that are parsed from Json, and there are details, which should be in table. I am using Xcode 4.4.1, and targeted for iOS 4.3 and above.
  The table height has been developed dynamic where the height of table varies  according to the height if cell height is changed on the run time. I question is, now how can I able to change the table height according to the number of cell present in that table so that user wont have to scroll separately in the table.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
TableView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 200 ,MIN(40 * [YourArray count], 600));
```

assuming `40` is the height of your cell, and minimum height for your tableview is `600`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but in my case, individual cell height also varies according to the content of the cell during run time. so I cant give static cell height. I have show more button which increases/decreases the cell height accordingly.

Comment: identify your cell height and put that no instead of `40`.

Answer (score 0):

Krunal solution will work fine if all the cells have the same height. However, if you have dynamic cell heights you have to follow these steps:

1- Set the height constraint for the table from the storyboard.

2- Drag the height constraint from the storyboard and create @IBOutlet for it in the viewController file.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

3- Then you can change the height for the table dynamicaly using this code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        super.updateViewConstraints()
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint?.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    })
}
```